# passing date to controller using ajax in mvc

Tags: c#, ajax, date, model-view-controller

I want to update my chart according to user date selection. here i am using chart js. So  i want to pass from date and to date value using Ajax to controller so that i can do data filters. But the problem is that the dates are not submitted to controller action.Please guide me where i have missed.

i have tried many links too but is not helping me.
[Post datetime to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479169/post-datetime-to-controller)
this is also not helping.

Here is my Script

```
<script>
    function SendDates() {
        var ListOfDates = [];
        ListOfDates.push($("#fromDate").val());
        ListOfDates.push($("#endDate").val());
        dates = JSON.stringify({ 'ListOfDates': ListOfDates });        
        alert(dates)        
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            url: "/dashboard/sendDates",
            data: dates ,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status == "successfull") {
                    alert("Dates were sent successfully ");
                } else {
                    alert("Dates werenot sent successfully ");
                }

            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        })
    }


</script>
```

and this is controller

```
[HttpPost]
     public JsonResult sendDates(DateTime receivedDates) {
            DateTime dates = receivedDates;  

            Debug.WriteLine(" Date is:"+ dates );                   
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = "successfull" }   
 };

}
```

when i change the data type DateTime to String in controller i get success message but seeing debug output there there is blank.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult sendDates(String receivedDates) {

                    var dates = receivedDates;   

                    Debug.WriteLine(" Date is:"+ dates );

                    return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = "successfull" }    };
                }
```

Comment: What is your backend language and framework? How is the route `/dashboard/sendDates` defined?

Comment: @Pablo its c# and i am using mvc framework.

Comment: I am not familiar with c#. I suggest adding the c# tag to the question. Also, include the specific MVC framework that you are using. Add a tag for it if available too. For me, the missing part is what is parsing the POST request JSON string and passing it to the controller action method as the frist parameter.

Comment: The first thing that stands out is that you want to push two dates but only have a param for one. You push from date and end date into a list/array but only accept datetime being a single date.

Comment: Also, not 100% on this but I believe the dates param in javascript should match the passed in param name in the action.

Comment: @Tomaltach i dont think its about params